# Stream is disposing before EndOfData is true

Tags: c#, csv, ftp, textfieldparser

I am writing a method that connects to an FTP, reads a csv file into a stream then uses a TextFieldParser to process the data.

It's all working except for an issue I'm getting when it gets about halfway through reading the CSV suddenly I get an ObjectDisposedException exception.  I've tried passing both the StreamReader & TextReader to the TextFieldParser but both result in the same problem.

Should I be downloading the CSV to a temporary local directory and then reading that or is there no issue reading a file from an FTP?  I figured there might be some server setting possibly timing out the stream before it reads the entire file.

```
FtpWebRequest request = (FtpWebRequest)FtpWebRequest.Create("REMOVED.csv");
request.Credentials = new NetworkCredential("xyz", "*******");
using (WebResponse response = request.GetResponse())
{
    using (Stream stream = response.GetResponseStream())
    {
        using (TextReader reader = new StreamReader(stream))
        {
            using (TextFieldParser parser = new TextFieldParser(reader))
            {
                parser.HasFieldsEnclosedInQuotes = true;
                parser.Delimiters = new string[] { "," };
                while (!parser.EndOfData) //exception is thrown here about 1500lines into csv
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(parser.ReadLine().ToString());
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

> LAST LINE OF OUTPUT BEFORE EXCEPTION THROWN
>
> 190500,Courier Delivery,Freight,Distributor,1,5,15/12/2014 16:44

If I should be downloading the file first, do I just use WebClient.DownloadFile() ?? How can I tell when the file has finished downloading to then read it?

**EDIT:**

System net tracing output shows the following

> System.Net.Sockets Verbose: 0 : [10412] Exiting Socket#24914721::Receive()    -> Int32#95
>   System.Net Information: 0 : [10412] FtpControlStream#15315213 - Received response [226-File successfully transferred
>   226 5.748 seconds (measured here), 30.91 Kbytes per second]
>   System.Net Information: 0 : [10412] FtpWebRequest#16868352::(Releasing FTP connection#15315213.)

**FURTHER EDIT**

The output from System.Net Tracing shows the last line of the CSV being received, so why is the parser being Disposed before it finishes??  I'm still quite new to programming so I'm not really sure how to proceed

Comment: Have you tried reading to a String array instead of TextFieldParser ? Also from where does the exception throw ? [Is it from parser ? ]

Comment: `WebClient.DownloadFile()` is synchronous, you can read the file immediately after the call completes. The original issue looks strange to me though: are you sure it's not in the code you stripped away?

Comment: I have commented all code that was stripped away, bar one line - Console.WriteLine(parser.ReadLine().ToString()); which I've readded.  the csv lines it fails on I added as "output" to the original post.  @KCdod the exception is thrown on the while(!parser.EndOfData)

Comment: Enable system.net tracing and check if connection is getting closed before it reads complete file.

Comment: Hi Panjak, please see my updated answer.  I added the system net tracing and it appears the file is successfully being read as transferred and all data is received (last row of CSV i can see in log) but it doesn't read to there, it disposes.

Comment: May be a timeout. Have you tried with some other file ? [ Specially with a shorter length ]

Comment: I don't think it is a Timeout as the stream reads to end, perhaps the stream is being disposed before the TextFieldParser reads to the end?  That would explain why it's crashing so close to the end of the CSV..

Comment: Possible duplicate of [C# Stream disposed before ending parsing and reading FTP File](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36839062/c-sharp-stream-disposed-before-ending-parsing-and-reading-ftp-file)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I was unable to figure out how to stop the stream disposing before I read to the end with my TextFieldParser, instead I did the following:

> ```
> Connect to FTP
> Read the file into a stream
> Copy the stream to a FileStream and create a temporary file
> Read the temporary file
> Delete the temporary file
> ```

This isn't very elegant but if anyone else comes across the above error know that downloading the file is an alternative.

Answer (score -1):

> Use the Peek method instead of EndOfData - havent tested this, but should work...

```
//...
  using (var response = request.GetResponse())
  {
    using (var stream = response.GetResponseStream())
    {
      using (var reader = new StreamReader(stream))
      {
        while (reader.Peek() != -1) //use Peek instead
        {
          Console.WriteLine(reader.ReadLine());
        }
      }
    }
  }
//...
```

Comment: `Peek` will abort the loop, whenever there's momentarily no data. What happens quite often with network streams.